# jQuery UI draggable over out event order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ui with draggable and droppable on a calendar type application.

The calendar is rendered as a table with seven cells in every row, each of these cells representing one day. Every day is divided into four quarters, represented as cells within another table within the calendar. These inner-tables have n rows where n is based on the number of jobs per month.

I have draggable divs that represent bookings, the bookings can consume any number of the quarters, as you are dragging them around I need to higlight the target consumed range. To do this I am using draggable over and out as below

```
over: function (event, ui) {
        // walk forward and highlight the correct cells
        //console.log('in');
                    var numCells = ui.draggable.attr('db:length') * 4;
        var me = jQuery(this);
        me.addClass('me');
        var cells = jQuery(".inner-table .allowableTarget td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            if (jQuery(cells[i]).hasClass('me')) {
                cells.slice(i, i + numCells).addClass('drop-hover');
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        // unhighlight the highlighted cells from over...

        //console.log('out');
        var items = jQuery(".inner-table td.drop-hover");
        items.removeClass('drop-hover');

        var me = jQuery(this);
        me.removeClass('me');

    },
```

This mostly works, as long as I am dragging from left to right its works fine. If I am dragging from right to left it does not. It appears that the reason for it is that depending on which way I am dragging the events fire in a different order. If I am dragging right to left the over for the new cells fires before the out from the old cell, unless it is the first cell of an inner table in which case it works when i drag to the last cell of the preceding inner table.

My questions are; is there either a better way to achieve what I want? Or a way to ensure that I always get the out called before the over?

Comment: Ah the obvious answer was to move the out stuff to the start of the over... anyone know a way to make it more efficient it seems a little laggy in ie?

Comment: although, that means that when they drag somewhere completely different it doesn't unhighlight the highlighted rows

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today, I didn't notice the cause (previous element) before your post, and of course it's a normal behavior.
To resolve my problem I simply put the "over" function in a setTimeout with 0 ms, so the "over" function is pushed in task queue and executed after the "out" function.

A great talk from Philip Roberts to understand this mechanism : http://vimeo.com/96425312

[EDIT]
Example : http://jsbin.com/rizuse/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Some example code of your solution would be helpful.

Comment: This answer helped me, and it works consistently.  I wrapped the contents of my 'over' function in:

`var t = setTimeout(function() { 
  // put code here 
}, 0);`

Reminder: `this` has a different context here, and you may need to do something like `var that = this` and use `that` in the body of your setTimeout function.  If your function wasn't using `this`, then you don't need to worry.